Zeroing days (for 60 days) after disease detection
I have repeat measures where participants (by 'site_specific') were tested weekly for a disease. I have a cumulative day total and # of days since previous test ('rolling_days'). Additionally I have a binary variable ('disease_detection') where 1 = disease detected. Finally, I have a 'date' variable that lists the day of disease_detection test.
My hopes are to 0 out 'rolling_days' everytime disease_detection = 1 and for the next 60 days, using data.
The approach could be to automatically 0 out the days or (2) create a Yes/no variable indicate a positive status and the next 60 days.
I have tried multiple ways but this is the most recent. It is getting close but is not accurate.
data_processed <- data %>%
  arrange(site_specific, date) %>%  # Ensure data is sorted
  group_by(site_specific) %>%
  mutate(
    zero_out = ifelse(disease_detection == 1, "Yes", NA)  # Set 'zero_out' to "Yes" when disease_detection = 1
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    detection_date = ifelse(disease_detection == 1, date, NA),
    detection_date = zoo::na.locf(detection_date, na.rm = FALSE)  # Forward fill detection_date
  ) ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    days_since_detection = as.numeric(date - detection_date),
    zero_out = ifelse(days_since_detection <= 60, "Yes", zero_out)  # Set 'zero_out' to "Yes" if within 60 days
  ) %>%
  select(-detection_date, -days_since_detection)  # Remove temporary columns

> dput(data)
structure(list(site_specific = c("HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", 
"HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", 
"HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", 
"HPB0002", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", 
"HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", 
"HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0005", "HPB0008", 
"HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", 
"HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", 
"HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0008", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", 
"HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", 
"HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", "HPB0009", 
"HPB0009", "HPB0010", "HPB0010", "HPB0010", "HPB0010", "HPB0010", 
"HPB0010", "HPB0010", "HPB0010", "HPB0010", "HPB0010", "HPB0010", 
"HPB0010", "HPB0013", "HPB0013", "HPB0013", "HPB0013", "HPB0013", 
"HPB0013", "HPB0013", "HPB0013", "HPB0013", "HPB0013", "HPB0013", 
"HPB0013", "HPB0013", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", 
"HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", 
"HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", "HPB0017", 
"HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", 
"HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", 
"HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0024", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", 
"HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", 
"HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0026", 
"HPB0026", "HPB0026", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", 
"HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", 
"HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", "HPB0035", 
"HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", 
"HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", 
"HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0047", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", 
"HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", 
"HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0058", 
"HPB0058", "HPB0058", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", 
"HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", 
"HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", "HPB0059", 
"HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", 
"HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", 
"HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0061", "HPB0070", "HPB0070", 
"HPB0070"), date = c("10/14/2020", "10/22/2020", "10/27/2020", 
"11/3/2020", "11/11/2020", "11/18/2020", "11/26/2020", "12/2/2020", 
"12/9/2020", "12/17/2020", "12/22/2020", "12/29/2020", "1/6/2021", 
"1/11/2021", "1/18/2021", "1/26/2021", "8/15/2020", "8/21/2020", 
"8/28/2020", "9/3/2020", "9/11/2020", "9/18/2020", "9/25/2020", 
"10/2/2020", "10/9/2020", "10/16/2020", "10/23/2020", "10/30/2020", 
"11/6/2020", "11/13/2020", "11/20/2020", "11/27/2020", "8/6/2020", 
"8/12/2020", "8/20/2020", "8/26/2020", "9/4/2020", "9/12/2020", 
"9/18/2020", "9/26/2020", "10/2/2020", "10/10/2020", "10/16/2020", 
"10/22/2020", "10/28/2020", "11/3/2020", "11/11/2020", "11/19/2020", 
"8/12/2020", "8/19/2020", "8/26/2020", "9/1/2020", "9/8/2020", 
"9/16/2020", "9/23/2020", "9/30/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/14/2020", 
"10/20/2020", "10/28/2020", "11/4/2020", "11/11/2020", "11/18/2020", 
"11/25/2020", "8/6/2020", "8/15/2020", "8/20/2020", "8/26/2020", 
"9/3/2020", "9/9/2020", "9/17/2020", "9/23/2020", "9/30/2020", 
"10/7/2020", "10/14/2020", "10/20/2020", "8/28/2020", "9/1/2020", 
"9/8/2020", "9/15/2020", "9/22/2020", "9/29/2020", "10/6/2020", 
"10/13/2020", "10/20/2020", "11/3/2020", "11/17/2020", "12/1/2020", 
"12/10/2020", "8/20/2020", "8/27/2020", "9/2/2020", "9/10/2020", 
"9/16/2020", "9/24/2020", "10/2/2020", "10/9/2020", "10/14/2020", 
"10/22/2020", "10/31/2020", "11/6/2020", "11/11/2020", "11/18/2020", 
"11/26/2020", "12/3/2020", "8/18/2020", "8/25/2020", "9/2/2020", 
"9/10/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/23/2020", "9/30/2020", "10/6/2020", 
"10/13/2020", "10/20/2020", "10/27/2020", "11/2/2020", "11/11/2020", 
"11/16/2020", "11/23/2020", "11/30/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/20/2020", 
"8/27/2020", "9/4/2020", "9/9/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/24/2020", 
"10/2/2020", "10/8/2020", "10/16/2020", "10/23/2020", "10/28/2020", 
"11/3/2020", "11/11/2020", "11/18/2020", "11/26/2020", "8/14/2020", 
"8/21/2020", "8/28/2020", "9/4/2020", "9/10/2020", "9/18/2020", 
"9/24/2020", "10/1/2020", "10/9/2020", "10/16/2020", "10/23/2020", 
"10/29/2020", "11/6/2020", "11/12/2020", "11/20/2020", "11/27/2020", 
"10/1/2020", "10/8/2020", "10/16/2020", "10/21/2020", "10/28/2020", 
"11/6/2020", "11/11/2020", "11/18/2020", "11/26/2020", "12/3/2020", 
"12/11/2020", "12/16/2020", "1/2/2021", "1/7/2021", "1/12/2021", 
"1/24/2021", "8/12/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/27/2020", "9/5/2020", 
"9/11/2020", "9/18/2020", "9/26/2020", "10/1/2020", "10/10/2020", 
"10/16/2020", "10/21/2020", "10/28/2020", "11/4/2020", "11/11/2020", 
"11/19/2020", "11/26/2020", "9/21/2020", "9/29/2020", "10/8/2020", 
"10/16/2020", "10/23/2020", "10/28/2020", "11/5/2020", "11/12/2020", 
"11/17/2020", "11/25/2020", "11/30/2020", "12/7/2020", "12/15/2020", 
"12/21/2020", "12/28/2020", "1/6/2021", "8/18/2020", "8/25/2020", 
"8/31/2020", "9/7/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/22/2020", "9/29/2020", 
"10/5/2020", "10/13/2020", "10/20/2020", "10/28/2020", "11/2/2020", 
"11/9/2020", "11/17/2020", "11/24/2020", "12/16/2020", "8/22/2020", 
"8/29/2020", "9/3/2020"), enroll_date = c("10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", 
"10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", 
"10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", 
"10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "10/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", 
"7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", 
"7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", 
"7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "8/4/2020", 
"8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", 
"8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", 
"8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "8/4/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", 
"7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", 
"7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", "7/30/2020", 
"8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", 
"8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", 
"8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/22/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", 
"8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", 
"8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", 
"8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/13/2020", "8/11/2020", 
"8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", 
"8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", 
"8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", "8/11/2020", 
"8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", 
"8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", 
"8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/5/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", 
"9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", 
"9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", 
"9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "9/24/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", 
"8/7/2020", "8/7/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", 
"9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", 
"9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", 
"9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "9/16/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", 
"8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", 
"8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", 
"8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/10/2020", "8/14/2020", 
"8/14/2020", "8/14/2020"), follow_days = c(7L, 15L, 20L, 27L, 
35L, 42L, 50L, 56L, 63L, 71L, 76L, 83L, 91L, 96L, 103L, 111L, 
8L, 14L, 21L, 27L, 35L, 42L, 49L, 56L, 63L, 70L, 77L, 84L, 91L, 
98L, 105L, 112L, 7L, 13L, 21L, 27L, 36L, 44L, 50L, 58L, 64L, 
72L, 78L, 84L, 90L, 96L, 104L, 112L, 8L, 15L, 22L, 28L, 35L, 
43L, 50L, 57L, 64L, 71L, 77L, 85L, 92L, 99L, 106L, 113L, 7L, 
16L, 21L, 27L, 35L, 41L, 49L, 55L, 62L, 69L, 76L, 82L, 6L, 10L, 
17L, 24L, 31L, 38L, 45L, 52L, 59L, 73L, 87L, 101L, 110L, 7L, 
14L, 20L, 28L, 34L, 42L, 50L, 57L, 62L, 70L, 79L, 85L, 90L, 97L, 
105L, 112L, 7L, 14L, 22L, 30L, 36L, 43L, 50L, 56L, 63L, 70L, 
77L, 83L, 92L, 97L, 104L, 111L, 8L, 15L, 22L, 30L, 35L, 42L, 
50L, 58L, 64L, 72L, 79L, 84L, 90L, 98L, 105L, 113L, 7L, 14L, 
21L, 28L, 34L, 42L, 48L, 55L, 63L, 70L, 77L, 83L, 91L, 97L, 105L, 
112L, 7L, 14L, 22L, 27L, 34L, 43L, 48L, 55L, 63L, 70L, 78L, 83L, 
100L, 105L, 110L, 122L, 5L, 15L, 20L, 29L, 35L, 42L, 50L, 55L, 
64L, 70L, 75L, 82L, 89L, 96L, 104L, 111L, 5L, 13L, 22L, 30L, 
37L, 42L, 50L, 57L, 62L, 70L, 75L, 82L, 90L, 96L, 103L, 112L, 
8L, 15L, 21L, 28L, 37L, 43L, 50L, 56L, 64L, 71L, 79L, 84L, 91L, 
99L, 106L, 128L, 8L, 15L, 20L), rolling.days = c(7L, 8L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 
6L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 
8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 
8L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
7L, 8L, 5L, 17L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
9L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 
5L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 
8L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 22L, 8L, 7L, 5L), disease_detection = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 
NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-220L))


Is this the actual input data for your included script? So dates are M/D/YYYY strings and you arranging those alphabetically?

it is the actual data I am using

Please check that your data and code are as you intend. You seem to be missing an %>% in the 10th line of your code, and probably have a missing step somewhere where you convert the "1/11/2021" text data into "2021-01-11" date data which would allow code like as.numeric(date - detection_date) to run.

This reprex assumes your option 1 (zeroing rolling.days) is the preferred solution, although the same logic can be applied to create your option 2.
It involves creating a temporary column, then using tidyr::fill() to fill down values from follow_days where disease_detection == 1. Once you have this temporary column, case_when() is used to zero the relevant rolling.days values.
Note that if you have date values, it is good practice to store them as Date class. I have used lubridate() for this purpose (although the date columns were not used in this solution). If you want to maintain your original date strings, simply create two new Date class columns and use them for your sorting/analysis etc.
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

data_processed <- data |>
  mutate(across(contains("date"), ~ mdy(.))) |>
  arrange(site_specific, date) |>
  group_by(site_specific) |>
  mutate(tmp = ifelse(disease_detection == 1, follow_days, NA)) |>
  fill(tmp, .direction = "down") |>
  mutate(rolling.days = case_when(is.na(tmp) ~ rolling.days,
                                  follow_days - tmp <= 60 ~ 0,
                                  .default = rolling.days)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-tmp)

data_processed
# # A tibble: 220 × 6
#    site_specific date       enroll_date follow_days rolling.days disease_detection
#    <chr>         <date>     <date>            <int>        <dbl>             <int>
#  1 HPB0002       2020-10-14 2020-10-07            7            7                 0
#  2 HPB0002       2020-10-22 2020-10-07           15            8                 0
#  3 HPB0002       2020-10-27 2020-10-07           20            5                 0
#  4 HPB0002       2020-11-03 2020-10-07           27            7                 0
#  5 HPB0002       2020-11-11 2020-10-07           35            8                 0
#  6 HPB0002       2020-11-18 2020-10-07           42            7                 0
#  7 HPB0002       2020-11-26 2020-10-07           50            0                 1
#  8 HPB0002       2020-12-02 2020-10-07           56            0                 0
#  9 HPB0002       2020-12-09 2020-10-07           63            0                 0
# 10 HPB0002       2020-12-17 2020-10-07           71            0                 0
# ℹ 210 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

filter(data_processed, site_specific == "HPB0026")
# # A tibble: 16 × 6
#    site_specific date       enroll_date follow_days rolling.days disease_detection
#    <chr>         <date>     <date>            <int>        <dbl>             <int>
#  1 HPB0026       2020-08-13 2020-08-05            8            8                 0
#  2 HPB0026       2020-08-20 2020-08-05           15            7                 0
#  3 HPB0026       2020-08-27 2020-08-05           22            7                 0
#  4 HPB0026       2020-09-04 2020-08-05           30            8                 0
#  5 HPB0026       2020-09-09 2020-08-05           35            5                 0
#  6 HPB0026       2020-09-16 2020-08-05           42            0                 1
#  7 HPB0026       2020-09-24 2020-08-05           50            0                 1
#  8 HPB0026       2020-10-02 2020-08-05           58            0                 1
#  9 HPB0026       2020-10-08 2020-08-05           64            0                 1
# 10 HPB0026       2020-10-16 2020-08-05           72            0                 1
# 11 HPB0026       2020-10-23 2020-08-05           79            0                 0
# 12 HPB0026       2020-10-28 2020-08-05           84            0                 0
# 13 HPB0026       2020-11-03 2020-08-05           90            0                 1
# 14 HPB0026       2020-11-11 2020-08-05           98            0                 0
# 15 HPB0026       2020-11-18 2020-08-05          105            0                 0
# 16 HPB0026       2020-11-26 2020-08-05          113            0                 0

